# How to find into mongodb to the last item of an array?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to find documents where last elements in an array equals to some value.
Array elements may be accessed by specific array position:

```
// i.e. comments[0].by == "Abe"
db.example.find( { "comments.0.by" : "Abe" } )
```

but how do i search using the last item as criteria?
i.e.

```
db.example.find( { "comments.last.by" : "Abe" } )
```

By the way, i'm using php

Comment: Do you want to find documents where last elements in an array equals to some value?

Comment: Then you can't do it. Unless you're storing array length in a separate field. But that still will require two queries. I'll be happy if someones proves me wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just doing :

```
db.products.find({'statusHistory.status':'AVAILABLE'},{'statusHistory': {$slice: -1}})
```

This gets me `products` for which the last `statusHistory` item in the array, contains the property `status='AVAILABLE'` .

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is old, but I found it on google after answering a [similar new question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21952273/2313887). So I thought this deserved the same treatment.

You can avoid the performance hit of [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) by using [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) instead:

```
db.example.aggregate([

    // Use an index, which $where cannot to narrow down
    {$match: { "comments.by": "Abe" }},

    // De-normalize the Array
    {$unwind: "$comments"},

    // The order of the array is maintained, so just look for the $last by _id
    {$group: { _id: "$_id", comments: {$last: "$comment"} }},

    // Match only where that $last comment by `by.Abe`
    {$match: { "comments.by": "Abe" }},

    // Retain the original _id order
    {$sort: { _id: 1 }}

])
```

And that should run rings around *$where* since we were able to narrow down the documents that **had** a comment by "Abe" in the first place. As warned, *$where* is going to test every document in the collection and never use an index even if one is there to be used.

Of course, you can also maintain the original document using the [technique described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21721480/2313887) as well, so everything would work just like a `find()`.

Just food for thought for anyone finding this.

---

### Update for Modern MongoDB releases

Modern releases have added the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) pipeline expression as well as [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) ( the latter as of 3.2, so that would be the minimal version here ) which in combination would allow a logical expression to inspect the last element of an array without processing an [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage:

```
db.example.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "comments.by": "Abe" }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$eq": [
          { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$comments.by", -1 ] },
          "Abe"
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

The logic here is done in comparison where [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) is getting the last index of the array `-1`, which is transformed to just an array of the values in the `"by"` property via [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/). This allows comparison of the single value against the required parameter, `"Abe"`.

Or even a bit more modern using [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) for MongoDB 3.6 and greater:

```
db.example.find({
  "comments.by": "Abe",
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [
      { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$comments.by", -1 ] },
      "Abe"
    ]
  }
})
```

This would be by far the most performant solution for matching the last element within an array, and actually expected to supersede the usage of [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) in most cases and especially here.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this in one go with this schema design. You can either store the length and do two queries, or store the last comment additionally in another field:

```
{
    '_id': 'foo';
    'comments' [
        { 'value': 'comment #1', 'by': 'Ford' },
        { 'value': 'comment #2', 'by': 'Arthur' },
        { 'value': 'comment #3', 'by': 'Zaphod' }
    ],
    'last_comment': {
        'value': 'comment #3', 'by': 'Zaphod'
    }
}
```

Sure, you'll be duplicating some data, but atleast you can set this data with `$set` together with the `$push` for the `comment`.

```
$comment = array(
    'value' => 'comment #3',
    'by' => 'Zaphod',
);

$collection->update(
    array( '_id' => 'foo' ),
    array(
        '$set' => array( 'last_comment' => $comment ),
        '$push' => array( 'comments' => $comment )
    )
);
```

Finding the last one is easy now!

Answer (score 5):

You could do this with a [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_where) operator:

```
db.example.find({ $where: 
    'this.comments.length && this.comments[this.comments.length-1].by === "Abe"' 
})
```

The usual slow performance caveats for `$where` apply. However, you can help with this by including `"comments.by": "Abe"` in your query:

```
db.example.find({
    "comments.by": "Abe",
    $where: 'this.comments.length && this.comments[this.comments.length-1].by === "Abe"' 
})
```

This way, the `$where` only needs to be evaluated against documents that include comments by Abe and the new term would be able to use an index on `"comments.by"`.

Comment: @fnaquira I know this is old, but on finding this I thought this deserved a **new** (and better) answer. Which I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why my answer above is deleted. I am reposting it. I am pretty sure without changing the schema, you should be able to do it this way.

```
db.example.find({ "comments:{$slice:-1}.by" : "Abe" }
```

// ... or

```
db.example.find({ "comments.by" : "Abe" }
```

This by default takes the last element in the array.

Comment: Both of these are wrong.  `$slice` is a projection operator, not a query operator, and the second query looks at all comments, not just the last one.

Comment: Somehow, the answer of ashwin has helped me because $slice indeed can be used in a query, according to MongoDB documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/