# How to sort results by month in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a *contacts* collection with documents similar to this:

```
{ Name: "John Doe", BirthDate: ISODate("1980-03-12T00:00:00.000Z"), Address: "..." }
```

I need to get all documents, sorted by the **month** part of the **BirthDate** field.
The result must include all fields of the document. The idea is to show the user which contacts have a birthday on each month.

I've tried to construct an aggregation, but can't quite figure out how to sort the *BirthDate* field using the `$month` operator.

Maybe I can use `$group`, but how do I make it show all fields of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is a trick to that, and depending on what you want to do you can take a couple of approaches. The most simple for is a matter of using [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) in the aggregation pipeline.

I'm working with a *sub-set* of what knowledge I have of your fields but the general concept is to define all of them in the [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) phase, plus the additional field:

```
db.collection.aggregate([

    // You probably want to do some matching first

    // Project your altered document form with a *new* field for "month"
    {"$project": {
        "Name": 1,
        "BirthDate": 1,
        "Address": 1,
        "month": { "$month": "$BirthDate" }               // Extra field for "month"
    }},

    // Sort by your month value
    {"$sort": { "month": 1 }},

    // Then just clean the extra part from your projection
    // ( if you need to )
    {"$project": {
        "Name": 1,
        "BirthDate": 1,
        "Address": 1,
    }},

])
```

If you need to do something more complex, that is going to involve some form of grouping or other operations, then **save** the document in the `_id` as long as you are doing things like grouping on the *whole* document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([

   // Save your document in the `_id` field
    {"$project": {
        _id: {
            _id: "$_id",
            "Name": 1,
            "BirthDate": 1,
            "Address": 1
        }
    }},
```

There was some more example usage of this posted here:

[How to get back the Original document back after aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721479/how-to-get-back-the-original-document-back-after-aggregation)

Comment: I thought going that way, and your example is great. But, the fact that I need to project all of the fields manually is bothering me. What if later I add more fields to the documents, or remove some, I will have to find all aggregations that do projection on that collection and fix them.
I hope to find a way to have all of the fields included automatically.

Comment: @Yev Anoying yes. From 2.6 there will be a `$$ROOT` variable that is an alias for the **whole** document in a given pipeline phase. At the moment there is no other way around this.

Comment: @Yev As a principle, I generally don't code these statements, (except when playing / devising ), but thet get **generated** in real world code. So that is how **I** deal with what you are describing.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. I'll do it manually then, and wait for 2.6.
Can you please post a link to the $$ROOT documentation? I can't find it on MongoDB's site.

Comment: @Yev I'll bump someone on that. If you look at the documentation and change the version to **2.6** (which you can do) you can look through other features. And there is RC1 of 2.6 out now if you are game. Here's the [release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/), but still no mention of these *hidden* vars there.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that doc. I'd be game, but need it in production pretty soon, no RC for me :( I'm not sure though whether they're releasing 2.6 in March or will go straight to 2.7 later.

Comment: @Yev 2.6 is the release. Dev branch was 2.5.x. It will be ready when it's ready. [JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5916) for $$ROOT