# what is the equivalent mongodb query for the following mysql query?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

what is the equivalent mongodb query for the following mysql query or how to write query to get the results

**SELECT name, species FROM `pet`
ORDER BY FIELD(species, 'dog','cat','snake','bird'), name ASC**

Comment: Currently MongoDB does not have the capacity to specify a sort like this, it is in the JIRA somewhere but currently the only way is really do this client side

Comment: thanks for your response @Sammaye.. Is there anyway to do this using mongodb aggregation function? ...

Comment: I don't think so, someone who has tried this before might know more than me but thinking about it I don't know of a good way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do to achieve this is **weight** your responses using aggregate

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
    { "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "species", 1
        "weight": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$species", "dog" ] },
            4,
            { "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$species", "cat" ] },
                3,
                { "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$species", "snake" ] },
                    2,
                    { "$cond": [
                       { "$eq": [ "$species", "bird" ] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]}
    },
    { "$sort": { "weight": -1 }}
])
```

So you use the [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator which is a [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary) operation to evaluate what the current value of the field is. If it matches the condition, assign the value to weight, if not move on to the next one, until if it did not match then assign 0.

Sort descending on the weight, and the results come out in the order you want.

You can see how to generate this nested structure in code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22198172/2313887).

Comment: thanks for your response. I hope it will help me. but my question will it affect the performance?

Comment: @vinothkumar What do you mean by performance? And correct me if I am wrong but your question reads as "how do I do this SQL" in mongoDB. The aggregation framework is **very** fast and much like the SQL you presented will be affected by a factor of how much data you actually have. The SQL you presented (where it is supported) affects performance.

Comment: I am not expert in DB management so i just wanted to know whether it will affect performance. Anyway i will use your example in my application. thank u so much..

Comment: @vinothkumar The general protocol here is to ask a concise question, get responses, and if the response meets the needs of your question, then you accept it. Asking **additional** questions outside of the scope of your **actual** question is generally not "in the spirit" of the Q&A forum that SO is. I can say from experience the the SQL statement you presented **will** impact performance since the matching on terms excludes the use of an index in sort. The same can  be said for the statement here. If you need further advice, then ask "another question". But your "question" has been answered.

Comment: @vinothkumar and your acceptance is missing why exactly?