# Executing String containing Query in MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I build a string,containing mongodb queries using PHP. How can i execute that Query.For example, lets consider my string as

```
$x = array(
    'tag_id'=>'$value',
    'content_id'=>'$content_id',
    'createdby'=>'test',
    'created_date'=>date('d-m-Y'))
```

Now this is the query which i want to execute. If i give this string like this `mongocollection->insert($x)`, Its saying , `mongodb exception, with no documents given`. So how can i convert this string into executable statement

Comment: Why are you building a string as opposed to just using native code?

Comment: @NeilLunn:iam building query which contains many documents. Each document differ by the value of 
`'KEY: tag_id'`, i am getting those tag_id values from one array. So only i am building a query. Something like this
`"array(
'tag_id'=>'$value',
'content_id'=>'$content_id',
'createdby'=>'test',
'created_date'=>date('d-m-Y')),
array(
'tag_id'=>'$value1',
'content_id'=>'$content_id',
'createdby'=>'test',
'created_date'=>date('d-m-Y')), array(
'tag_id'=>'$value2',
'content_id'=>'$content_id',
'createdby'=>'test',
'created_date'=>date('d-m-Y'))"`

Comment: So still, why are you not using native code? It's code, not hardcoding. This is not SQL, so you can actually dynamically build data structures using push etc.

Comment: If i use push, mutiple inserts statements have to be compiled(forgive my ignorance ,if i am wrong),instead i am using `batchInsert` statement, single time, query will be compiled.

Comment: Not mongo $push. I'm talking about building your data structure (which is what a query is) in code. Something I [**posted**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198172/generating-a-structure-for-aggregation) a while ago might serve as a better example for you to look at.

Comment: Did that actually clarify things for you? I just was not sure you were understanding the difference of working in a native dynamic language form as opposed to "constructing queries" in something like SQL.

Comment: @NeilLunn: No neil. I dont have any knowledge about working in native dynamic language form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
//Your collection name
$collection = $m->selectDB("foo")->selectCollection("bar");

$x = array(
    'tag_id'=>'$value',
    'content_id'=>'$content_id',
    'createdby'=>'test',
    'created_date'=>new MongoDate('d-m-Y'));

$collection->insert($x);
```