# Mongodb $in not return correct sequence

Tags: php, mongodb

I have query

```
  $cursor = $collection->find(array('id' =>array('$in'=>array(4,3,2,1))), array('name'));
         foreach($cursor as $fild)
                {
               echo  $fild['name'].'<br>';
                }
```

return

```
    Need for speed: Most Wanted
    Pro Evolution Soccer 2014
    Fifa 2014
    Star Craft 2
```

If I change order in array like (3,2,4,1).
Return

```
Need for speed: Most Wanted
Pro Evolution Soccer 2014
Fifa 2014
Star Craft 2
```

must return

```
Fifa 2014
Pro Evolution Soccer 2014
Star Craft 2
Need for speed: Most Wanted
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're never sorting...?

Comment: You cannot sort by the $in

Comment: `$in` doesn't guarantee an order of responses. You'd need to sort on another field, or sort in your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this is not how the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator works, for MongoDB or in really any equivalent form in any database. So the order you put the arguments in is not maintained in your results as you seem to be expecting them to.

There are however a couple of approaches you can take in order to achieve this. The first is by some creative use of the aggregation pipeline:

```js
var selections = [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ];

db.collection.aggregate([
   // $match is like a standard "find" query
   { "$match": {
       "id": { "$in": selections  }
   }},

   // Project your field(s) and a sorting field
   { "$project": {
       "_id": 0,
       "name": 1,
       "order": { "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [ "$id", 4 ] },
          1,
          { "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$id", 2 ] },
              2,
              { "$cond": [
                  { "$eq": [ "$id", 3 ] },
                  3,
                  4
              ]}
          ]}
       ]}
   }},

   // Sort on the generated field
   { "$sort": { "order": } }
])
```

So by using the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator, which is a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), you are evaluating the current value of `id` in order to determine which sort order to assign. Of course you would actually generate the pipeline contents for this condition in code, using a method similar to what is [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22213246/2313887).

Of course if that seems all a little too complex, even though you would be best off doing it that way, then you can approach the problem is a similar way using mapReduce. But as this uses JavaScript code in an interpreter and does not use native code like [**`aggregate`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) does, then this will run slower:

```js
var selections = [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ];

db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(
            selections.indexOf( this.id ),
            this.name
        );            
    },
    function(){},
    { 
        "query": { "id": { "$in": selections } },
        "scope": { "selections": selections },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

And this way takes advantage of how mapReduce sorts the emitted key values from the mapper, so by positioning by the index value in the array you maintain the sort order.

So that gives you a couple of approaches you can use to generate a sort order "on the fly" from something like the order of arguments in an array.