# How to use a Javascript object inside mongodb aggregation pipeline?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a JS object `norm` which I want to use inside mongo aggregation pipeline, like this:

```js
var norm = { 
    1: 1, 
    2: 1.16,
    3: 1.413,
    4: 1.622,
    5: 1.6,
    6: 1.753,
    7: 3.001,
    8: 2.818,
    9: 3.291,
    10: 2.824,
    11: 2.993,
    12: 2.699,
    13: 1.099,
    14: 1.035,
    15: 1.172,
    16: 1.013,
    17: 0.9936,
    18: 1.069
};

db.mycoll.aggregate([
    {$match : 
        {"_id.day" : ISODate("2014-06-19T00:00:00.000Z"), 
         "_id.lt" : "l",
         "_id.rt" : "rltdlsts",
         "_id.m": false   }
    },

    {$unwind: '$value.rl'},

    {$match: {'value.rl.p': {$gte: 1, $lte: 18} } },

    {$group: {_id: '$value.rl.a', 
                v: {$sum: '$value.rl.v'},
                nv: { $sum: { $multiply: [ norm['$value.rl.p'], '$value.rl.v' ] } },
                c: {$sum: '$value.rl.c'}
            }},

    {$project: {
        _id: "$_id",
        'v': "$v",
        'c': "$c",
        'nv': "$nv"
      }
    },

    {$sort: {'_id': 1}}
])
```

I get results like this, where `nv` is always 0:

```js
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "v" : 89172,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 604
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "v" : 67872,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 296
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "v" : 33999,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 13
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 6,
            "v" : 4727,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 6
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 8,
            "v" : 913118,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 14055
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 9,
            "v" : 204099,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 3021
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 11,
            "v" : 151711,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 1075
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 12,
            "v" : 196369,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 601
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 13,
            "v" : 277705,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 2302
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 14,
            "v" : 64005,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 970
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 15,
            "v" : 54558,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 326
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 16,
            "v" : 74576,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 305
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 17,
            "v" : 1144,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 18,
            "v" : 1023,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 19,
            "v" : 54511,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 98
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 20,
            "v" : 674,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 21,
            "v" : 3359,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 22,
            "v" : 496402,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 3786
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 23,
            "v" : 293212,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 1904
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 24,
            "v" : 764087,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 8847
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 25,
            "v" : 291358,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 7012
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 28,
            "v" : 2933,
            "nv" : 0,
            "c" : 27
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You can't do that because the pipeline is evaluated once and then sent to the server for execution where `norm` isn't available.  Map-Reduce is probably your best bet here.

Comment: right, you can't do exactly what you are doing, but you can set up an aggregation pipeline with conditional expressions to use the correct multiplier depending on the value of '$value.rl.p' - it won't look pretty, but it can be done programmatically.

Comment: Thx, @JohnnyHK Will MR my way out :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this under the aggregation framework without resorting to mapReduce. Recent MongoDB 2.6 and greater versions have some operators to help here using [**`$let`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) and [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) for defining a variable and processing the array.

Your external declaration looks better for these purposes like this:

```js
var norm = [
    { "key": 1, "value": 1 }, 
    { "key": 2, "value": 1.16 },
    { "key": 3, "value": 1.413 },
    { "key": 4, "value": 1.622 },
    { "key": 5, "value":  1.6 },
    { "key": 6, "value": 1.753 },
    { "key": 7, "value":  3.001 },
    { "key": 8, "value":  2.818 },
    { "key": 9, "value": 3.291 },
    { "key": 10,"value": 2.824 },
    { "key": 11, "value": 2.993 },
    { "key": 12, "value": 2.699 },
    { "key": 13, "value": 1.099 },
    { "key": 14, "value": 1.035 },
    { "key": 15, "value": 1.172 },
    { "key": 16, "value": 1.013 },
    { "key": 17, "value": 0.9936 },
    { "key": 18, "value": 1.069 }
];
```

And then process the aggregate statement:

```js
db.mycoll.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "_id.day" : ISODate("2014-06-19T00:00:00.000Z"), 
        "_id.lt" : "l",
        "_id.rt" : "rltdlsts",
        "_id.m": false
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$value.rl" },

    { "$match": { "value.rl.p": { "$gte": 1, "$lte": 18 } } },

    { "$project": {
        "value": 1,
        "norm": {
            "$let": {
               "vars": {
                   "norm": norm
               },
               "in": {
                   "$setDifference": [
                       { "$map": {
                           "input": "$$norm",
                           "as": "norm",
                           "in": {
                               "$cond": [
                                   { "$eq": [ "$$norm.key", "$value.rl.p" ] },
                                   "$$norm.value",
                                   false
                               ]
                           }
                       }},
                       [false]
                   ]
               }
            }               
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$norm" }

    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$value.rl.a", 
        "v": { "$sum": "$value.rl.v" },
        "c": { "$sum": "$value.rl.c" },
        "nv": { "$sum": { "$multiply": [ "$norm", "$value.rl.v" ] } }
    }}
])
```

In that [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage you are actually injecting the external declaration as an array variable into the pipeline and then processing each element to match your existing "value.rl.p" keys. This only returns the single matching value, so the further use of [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) really only just makes the single element array result a singular value for use in the later [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) statement.

The traditional approach in earlier versions where the operators are not supported is to use a nested [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) statement to evaluate each value:

```js
db.mycoll.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "_id.day" : ISODate("2014-06-19T00:00:00.000Z"), 
        "_id.lt" : "l",
        "_id.rt" : "rltdlsts",
        "_id.m": false
    }},

    { "$unwind": "$value.rl" },

    { "$match": { "value.rl.p": { "$gte": 1, "$lte": 18 } } },

    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$value.rl.a", 
        "v": { "$sum": "$value.rl.v" },
        "c": { "$sum": "$value.rl.c" },
        "nv": { "$sum": { "$multiply": [ 
            { "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 2 },
                1.16
                { "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 3 },
                    1.413,
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 4 },
                        1.622,
                        { "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 5 },
                            1.6,
                            { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 6 },
                                1.753,
                                { "$cond": [
                                    { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 7 },
                                    3.001,
                                    { "$cond": [
                                        { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 8 },
                                        2.818,
                                        { "$cond": [
                                            { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 9 },
                                            3.291,
                                            { "$cond": [
                                                { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 10 },
                                                2.824,
                                                { "$cond": [
                                                    { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 11 },
                                                    2.993,
                                                    { "$cond": [
                                                        { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 12 },
                                                        2.699,
                                                        { "$cond": [
                                                            { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 13 },
                                                            1.099,
                                                            { "$cond": [
                                                                { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 14 },
                                                                1.035,
                                                                { "$cond": [
                                                                    { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 15 },
                                                                    1.172,
                                                                    { "$cond": [
                                                                        { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 16 },
                                                                        1.013,
                                                                        { "$cond": [
                                                                            { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 17 },
                                                                            0.9936,
                                                                            { "$cond": [
                                                                                { "$eq": [ "$value.rl.p", 18 },
                                                                                1.069,
                                                                                1
                                                                            ]}
                                                                        ]}
                                                                    ]}
                                                                ]}
                                                            ]}
                                                        ]}
                                                    ]}
                                                ]}
                                            ]}
                                        ]}
                                    ]}
                                ]}
                            ]}
                        ]}
                    ]}
                ]}
            ]},
            "$value.rl.v" 
        ]}}
    }}
])
```

It looks noisy but it is the next most efficient form to the query previously shown above. In reality you would generate the pipeline stage is a similar way to as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22213246/2313887).

Comment: Noisy, but impressive.

Comment: Is there any way of dynamically access mongodb document field? for example, if norm object has a field called factor, can I dynamically get field value from mongo document based on the factor field?