# ORDER BY FIELD in mongoDB without using aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I there a way to do `ORDER BY FIELD` in MongoDB?

In Mysql there is something like:

```
SELECT id, name, priority
FROM mytable
ORDER BY FIELD(priority, "core", "board", "other")
```

Can this be achieved in MongoDB?

Similar query is answered in : [How to ORDER BY FIELD VALUE in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607800/how-to-order-by-field-value-in-mongodb) But this does not answer the question.

Above link uses aggregate function. What I want to achieve is without aggregate and something with in find.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I am looking for something with out aggregate.

Comment: No way to do it server-side with `find`, but you can do it client-side [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32385762/1259510).

Comment: If that is so then this is not a duplicate question. question clearly states that I want is without aggregate and something with in find. which is not addressed anywhere in that duplicate link.

Comment: Well you added that part in an edit after your question was marked a duplicate. But both questions clearly desire a `find` based solution (which doesn't exist server-side), so I don't see much point in reopening it unless you're looking for a client-side solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not currently. MongoDB only allows to sort a field by normal old ascending and descending order. You cannot give a custom sort order of priority or anything.

The closest would be to use the aggregation framework to assign values to the field to sort the way you want. Though this will not work well with large queries so I would not recommend it.

Comment: yes thats true. It doesn't sync well with large queries and maintaining it is a pain. Any other way you can suggest for?

Comment: @user2520670 I cannot think of one. It is a currently limitation MongoDB has

Answer (score 0):

Yes MongoDB has "Order By" functionality it is achieved using `sort()` see below for two primitive examples of how to use:

`db.collection.find({}).sort({"fieldName" : 1})`

For descending sort use:

`db.collection.find({}).sort({"fieldName" : -1})`

Comment: That's not what he asked, this is very specific SQL syntax for sorting upon the values for the field, not the field itself

Comment: @Sammaye you can use sort to achieve a similar functionality i believe. I do not come from an SQL background but as i understand docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes  (scroll to using sort on multiple fields) will yield the same or similar results. let me know your thoughts and i will update my answer to match. Thanks it seems this question keeps on giving.

Comment: Not really. He is not sorting alphabetically there as such MongoDB simply cannot do that sever-side, i.e. he is sorting by c over b