# Retrieve selected sub arrays with particular key value pair of a document in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to retrieve a list of sub arrays of a document which meets a particular condition.

```js
"_id" : "something",
"players" : [
    {
        "Name" : "Sunny"
        "score": 20
    },
    {
        "Name" : "John"
        "score" : 40
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Alice"
        "score" : 20
    },
    etc...
]
```

I wanted output of those with score = 20 like

```js
{
    "Name" : "Sunny"
    "score": 20
},
{
    "Name" : "Alice"
    "score" : 20
}
```

But I tried querying with:

```js
db.collection.find(
    { "players.score":20, "_id":"something" },
    { "players" :1 }
)
```

But it gives me all the 3 sub arrays like

```js
{
    "Name" : "Sunny"
    "score": 20
},
{
    "Name" : "John"
    "score" : 40
},
{
     "Name" : "Alice"
    "score" : 20
}
```

If I use projector "$" or $matchelement like:

```js
db.collection.find({ "players.$.score":20, "_id":"something" }
```

It gives the very first array example

```js
{
    "Name" : "Sunny"
    "score": 20
}
```

Can anyone help me out with correct query for this .
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator will **only** match the **first** element found in a matching array condition. In order to just *filter* the elements you want, use [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Uwinds the array (de-normalize)
    { "$unwind": "$players" },

    // Match just the elements you want
    { "$match": { "players.score": 20 } },

    // Push everything back into an array like it was        
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "players": { "$push": { 
            "name": "$players.name",
            "score": "$players.score"
        }} 
    }}
])
```

If your document has more detail and you need that back as well, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721479/how-to-get-back-the-original-document-back-after-aggregation).

For the record, the other operator you were trying other than the direct **dot** `.` notation was [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/).

Comment: @Aditya How is copying code your own answer? And what you have posted does not produce the results you asked for in your question. "I wanted output of those with score = 20 like" and the listing is the documents in the array. Which is what $push is doing here. Leaving it unwound is not the state of the document as it was.

Comment: @Aditya Though I probably should have checked in the code that the array was being reconstructed correctly. Which it does now with an edit. The correct practice here is to accept the answer of those who help you.

Comment: i actual used the same query you provided i dint change anything .i wanted to edit the previous comment but it dint allow me .

Comment: i even wanted to upvote ur post but i do not have enough rep to do so.

Comment: @Aditya You **can** accept and answer. Which is the right thing to do when gained knowledge helps you. And I believe that even increases your rep score. If not only a new badge to your name.