# Get the only one sub-subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of documents like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("532d4e7d569c9e4574d5156e"),
  "title" : "Book Title"
  "author" : "Book Author",
  "owner" : "532d4e7c569c9e4574d51568",
  "pages" : [
    {
      "texts" : [
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("532d4e7d569c9e4574d51572"),
          "paragraphs" : [ ],
          "format" : [ ],
          "position" : {
            "y" : 0,
            "x" : 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "images" : [
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("532d4e7f569c9e4574d51573"),
          "position" : {
            "y" : 0,
            "x" : 0
          }
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("532d4e7d569c9e4574d51571"),
      "videos" : [ ],
      "audios" : [ ],
      "images" : [ ],
      "texts" : [ ],
      "animations" : [ ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to get the only `text` subdocument with `_id`:

```
db.projects.find({'pages.texts._id': ObjectId("532d4e7d569c9e4574d51572")}, {'pages.$.texts.$': 1}).pretty()
```

but it's not works.

I want to get only this part of document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("532d4e7d569c9e4574d51572"),
  "paragraphs" : [ ],
  "format" : [ ],
  "position" : {
    "y" : 0,
    "x" : 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. You say you want `texts` from a particular document that your **projection** does not even match the "path" to `texts`. Are you maybe trying to **just** return **one** item of `texts`? Whichever one that is of course :/

Comment: yes, I want to get a one item of `texts` by `text._id`.

Comment: I'm a little to fix the issue, I hope they will be a little more clear

Comment: Language. I understand. Take a moment. You are asking for `videos`. Can you **edit** your question to show what it is you want to see?

Comment: Okey. Of course. Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator:

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of the  field that is included in the query results to contain the **first** matching element. To specify an array element to update, see the positional $ operator for updates.

You have **two** arrays. **First** is `pages`. **Second** is `texts`.

The "position" is **only** matched on the **first** array and not again. You **can** do
 this with [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) :

```js
Projects.aggregate([
       // Match documents
       { "$match": {
           "pages.texts._id": ObjectId("532d4e7d569c9e4574d51572")
       }},

       // Unwind the pages array
       { "$unwind": "$pages" },

       // Unwind the "texts" array
       { "$unwind": "$pages.texts" },

       // Filter array
       { "$match": {
           "pages.texts._id": ObjectId("532d4e7d569c9e4574d51572")
       }},

       // Re-form
       { "$group": {
           "_id": "$_id",
           "texts": { "$push": "$pages.texts"  }
       }}
    ],
    function(err, res) {
       // do things with res or err here
})
```

And the [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate).

More on [aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

More reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721479/how-to-get-back-the-original-document-back-after-aggregation)

Comment: is it ok: `"texts": { "$push": { "$pages.texts" } }`?

Comment: @AntonShuvalov Read [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Comment: @AntonShuvalov This is [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and not **JavaScript**. Follow the "link". The "pipeline" is formatted as JSON. Same as `.find()`

Comment: I think, it's mistape: `"$push": _{_ "$pages.texts" _}_`. Without this braces all works perfect, but with it I get `syntax error`.

Comment: Awesome) In mongodb console all works correct, but how I can do this with mongoose? [This](https://gist.github.com/shuvalov-anton/9705337) doesn't works for me. https://gist.github.com/shuvalov-anton/9705337

Comment: @AntonShuvalov And the mongoose way. Assuming `Projects` as the model. In the edit.

Comment: I found the reason of the problem with mongoose. `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId(req.params.textID);` return undefined, and when I use just string with `_id` it doesn't finds anything.

Comment: Fixed. All's right with `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`. Thank you so much!