# Get part of array value

Tags: mongodb

I have an object in the database that looks like:

```
{
  'name':  'foo',
  'table':
  [
    {
      'date' : ISODate("2000-01-13T23:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      'date' : ISODate("2000-01-14T23:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      'date' : ISODate("2000-01-15T23:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      'date' : ISODate("2000-01-16T23:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      'date' : ISODate("2000-01-17T23:00:00Z")
    }
  ]
}
```

I wish to query for the following result:

```
{
  'name':  'foo',
  'table':
  [
    {
      'date' : ISODate("2000-01-15T23:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      'date' : ISODate("2000-01-16T23:00:00Z")
    }
  ]
}
```

So I'm looking for a way to extract the children that is between two different dates.

---

So far I have tried the following:

```
db.stock.find({'table.date' : {$gte : '2000-01-15', $lt : '2000-01-17'}});

db.stock.find({'table.date' : {$gte : new Date('2000-01-15'), $lt : new Date('2000-01-17')}});

db.stock.find({'table.date' : {$gte : '2000-01-15T23:00:00Z', $lt : '2000-01-17T23:00:00Z'}});

db.stock.find({'table.date' : {$gte : ISODate('2000-01-15T23:00:00Z'), $lt : ISODate('2000-01-17T23:00:00Z')}});

db.stock.find({'table.date' : {$gte : new Date('2000-01-15T23:00:00Z'), $lt : new Date('2000-01-17T23:00:00Z')}});
```

---

Is this possible to do? If so, how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for `.find()` to "filter" the returned elements of an array by itself. You can use the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator with a match condition to "project" **one** matching element only ( see the documentation ).

The reason here is that the query here is **not** matching the array elements, but rather the **document** that *"contains"* the matching array elements.

But to "filter" elements to just the ones you want, you need to use [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.stock.aggregate([
  // Matching first is a good idea to filter the documents that contain
  // the matching elements
  { "$match": { 
      "table.date": { 
          "$gte": new Date("2000-01-15"), 
           "$lt": new Date("2000-01-17")
      }
   }},              

   // Unwind the array, this "de-normalizes"
   { "$unwind": "$table" },

  // Now use the match to actually "filter" results in the array
  { "$match": { 
      "table.date": { 
          "$gte": new Date("2000-01-15"), 
           "$lt": new Date("2000-01-17")
      }
   }},              

   // Group the results back by a "key", probably the document
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "table": { "$push": "$table" }
   }}

])
```

Also worth noting from your examples that you **need** to use dates as actual **date types** and not "strings". This is also true in other language implementations, where the native **date type** will be sent as a BSON date to the MongoDB server where it can be compared internally.

For more information on returning the **original** document form with this type of query, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721479/how-to-get-back-the-original-document-back-after-aggregation).