# Filtering a list of votes where more than x matches are found

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following vote data in a large collection:

```js
{
    "user_id" : ObjectId("53ac7bce4eaf6de4d5601c1a"),
    "article_id" : ObjectId("53ab27504eaf6de4d5601be5"),
    "score" : 5
},
{
    "user_id" : ObjectId("53ac7bce4eaf6de4d5601c1b"),
    "article_id" : ObjectId("53ab27504eaf6de4d5601be5"),
    "score" : 3
},
{
    "user_id" : ObjectId("53ac7bce4eaf6de4d5601c1c"),
    "article_id" : ObjectId("53ab27504eaf6de4d5601be5"),
    "score" : 3
},
...
```

I'm looking to filter this collection where more than 3 votes have been obtained for a single article (as above) and output as-is (excluding any vote entries on articles < 3 total votes).

Any help much appreciated. This collection can be huge so efficiency would be ideal.

Comment: What are you actually asking here? All articles have the same "id". So do you want individual documents or the total per article to be less than three?

Comment: I want to discard any vote entries (documents) where the article voted on has less than 3 votes (3 document entries for that article_id) in total (ignore vote score, just a count of document entries-total votes). Does that make sense?

Comment: Didn't really answer the question. All three documents are for the same article. Does the "sum" of the "votes" field need to be less than 3 for the document to be shown or what do you mean? If you are not clear, I see answers here saying `"votes": { "$gt": 3 }` unless that is basically what you want. But seems pretty basic.

Comment: I changed vote to score to avoid confusion. Each document = 1 vote. Each vote can have a score (1-5). I'm not interested in the score of the vote but the count of votes themselves. The above example is 3 different users voting on the same article, so this should be output as-is with what I'm asking. If there was a fourth entry, on another article, this wouldn't be output since there would be only one vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally not something you do in a single operation, but you can do this if those really are your only fields and there are not too many matching documents.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$article_id",
        "docs": {
            "$push": {
                "user_id": "$user_id",
                "article_id": "$article_id",
                "score": "$score"
            }
        },
        "votes": { "$sum": 1 }
     }},
     { "$match": { "votes": { "$gt": 3 } } },
     { "$unwind": "$docs" },
     { "$project": {
         "user_id": "$docs.user_id",
         "article_id": "$docs.article_id",
         "score": "$docs.score"
     }}
])
```

You can clean that up a little with MongoDB 2.6 and greater which provides a system variable in the pipeline for [**`$$ROOT`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$article_id",
        "docs": {
            "$push": "$$ROOT"
        },
        "votes": { "$sum": 1 }
     }},
     { "$match": { "votes": { "$gt": 3 } } },
     { "$unwind": "$docs" },
     { "$project": {
         "user_id": "$docs.user_id",
         "article_id": "$docs.article_id",
         "score": "$docs.score"
     }}
])
```

Otherwise you can accept that you are doing this in a few steps and process the list of "article_id" values returned with a "count" greater than three:

```js
var ids = db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$article_id",
        "votes": { "$sum": 1 }
     }},
     { "$match": { "votes": { "$gt": 3 } } },
]).toArray().map(function(x){ return x._id });

db.collection.find({ "article_id": { "$in": ids } })
```

If that was a shell operation then you would use the "results" key from the array of results that was returned by default in versions earlier to 2.6.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm beginning to understand this more after reading through these answers you're providing. Just on another point (if you would be so kind :)) - if I wanted to make sure that each vote document is unique, is there a way to do a composite ID? Like ID(user_id, article_id)? Save some space from the auto inserted Id.

Comment: @dolyth Absolutely. Just like how you can even do with an actual `_id` field on collection documents you can "composite" the `_id` value which is used on aggregation `$group`. It is a common approach, so there would be many examples here on SO if you searched through the answers given on the tag for aggregation-framework. A very basic "all document" example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21721480/2313887)

Comment: I'm using robomongo and ran your first block of code. It's giving me the right amount of articles but the output it just the article_id (no score visible). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @dolyth The paths may not have been correct. Quick typing that has been corrected.