# Using $slice operator to get last element of array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to get the last element of an array based on a condition in mongodb?

I am unable to use slice. Here is my input:

```
{ "1" : { "relevancy" : [  "Y" ] } }
{ "1" : { "relevancy" : [  "Y",  "Y" ] } }
{ "1" : { "relevancy" : [  "N" ] } }
{ "1" : { "relevancy" : [  "Y",  "Y" ] } }
{ "1" : { "relevancy" : [  "Y",  "N" ] } }
{ "1" : { "relevancy" : [  "N" ] } }
{ "1" : { "relevancy" : [  "Y",  "N" ] } }
```

I want to count the number of rows having "Y" as last element of the "relevancy" array.

With the input records above, it should be 3.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you would be aware by now, [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) is only used in projection to limit the array elements returned in the results. So you would be stuck with processing the list programmatically with results from a find().

A better approach is to use [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). But first let's consider how *$slice* is used:

```js
> db.collection.find({},{ relevancy: {$slice: -1} })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c0"), "relevancy" : [  "Y" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c2"), "relevancy" : [  "Y" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c3"), "relevancy" : [  "N" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c4"), "relevancy" : [  "Y" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c6"), "relevancy" : [  "N" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c7"), "relevancy" : [  "N" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c8"), "relevancy" : [  "N" ] }
```

So you get the last array element, but you are stuck with looping the results as you can't *match* the last element value. You might as well have just done this in code.

Now let's look at *aggregate* :

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match things so we get rid of the documents that will never match, but it will
    // still keep some of course since they are arrays, that *may* contain "N"
    { "$match": { "relevancy": "Y" } },

    // De-normalizes the array
    { "$unwind": "$relevancy" },

    // The order of the array is retained, so just look for the $last by _id
    { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "relevancy": { "$last": "$relevancy" } }},

    // Match only the records with the results you want
    { "$match": { "relevancy": "Y" }},

    // Oh, and maintain the original _id order [ funny thing about $last ]
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

Even if this would be your first usage of aggregate(), I encourage you to **learn it**. It is perhaps your most useful problem solving tool. Certainly has been for me. Put each step in *once* at a time if you are learning.

Also not sure on your document form, all the `1: { ... }` sub-document notation appears to be a mistake but you should clear that up or adjust the code above to reference `"1.relevancy"` instead. I hope your documents actually look more like this though:

```js
{ "relevancy" : [  "Y" ] , "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c0") }
{ "relevancy" : [  "Y",  "Y" ] , "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c2") }
{ "relevancy" : [  "N" ], "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c3") }
{ "relevancy" : [  "Y",  "Y" ], "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c4") }
{ "relevancy" : [  "Y",  "N" ], "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c6") }
{ "relevancy" : [  "N" ], "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c7") }
{ "relevancy" : [  "Y",  "N" ], "_id" : ObjectId("530824b95f44eac1068b45c8") }
```

---

### MongoDB 3.2.x and upwards

Of course MongoDB 3.2 introduces an "aggregation" operator for [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) and an even better [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator that removes the need for any `$unwind` and `$group` processing. After the initial `$match` query you just make a "logical match" with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "relevancy": "Y" } },
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [{ "$arrayElemAt": [ "$relevancy", -1 ], "Y" ] },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}   
])
```

That is going to do the inspection on the last element of the array when deciding whether to `$$KEEP` or `$$PRUNE` the documents from the returned results.

If you still wanted the "projection" then you can actually add the `$slice`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "relevancy": "Y" } },
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [{ "$arrayElemAt": [ "$relevancy", -1 ], "Y" ] },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }},
    { "$project": { "relevancy": { "$slice": [ "$relevancy", -1 ] } } }
])
```

Or the alternate approach of:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "relevancy": "Y" } },
    { "$project": { "relevancy": { "$slice": [ "$relevancy", -1 ] } } },
    { "$match": { "relevancy": "Y" } }
])
```

But is probably less costly to do the `$redact` first and "then" do any re-shaping in `$project.

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, the aggregation operator [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/last-array-element/) can be used to access the last element of an array:

```
// { "1": { "relevancy": ["Y"] } }
// { "1": { "relevancy": ["Y", "Y"] } }
// { "1": { "relevancy": ["N"] } }
// { "1": { "relevancy": ["Y", "Y"] } }
// { "1": { "relevancy": ["Y", "N"] } }
// { "1": { "relevancy": ["N"] } }
// { "1": { "relevancy": ["Y", "N"] } }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { last: { $last: "$1.relevancy" } } },
  // { "last": "Y" }
  // { "last": "Y" }
  // { "last": "N" }
  // { "last": "Y" }
  // { "last": "N" }
  // { "last": "N" }
  // { "last": "N" }
  { $match: { "last": "Y" } },
  // { "last": "Y" }
  // { "last": "Y" }
  // { "last": "Y" }
  { $count: "result" }
  // { "result" : 3 }
])
```