# MongoDb Remove last element from array if length is greater

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using Mongodb and the stucture is as below:

```
**{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5693af5d62f0d4b6af5124f1"),
    "uid" : 1,
    "terms" : [
        "sasasdsds",
        "test",
        "abcd"
    ]
}**
```

I want to remove the last element from array if the length of it is greater than 10.
Is it possible to be done in a single query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952005/using-slice-operator-to-get-last-element-of-array-in-mongodb

Comment: @Undefined_variable Not quite, as though that does point out projection of an array to a specified length, it addresses neither the matching of documents of at least 10 array members nor the removal of the last element as the question asks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it is possible. What you use is a property of "dot notation" to test that the array contains at least 11 members and then apply the [`$pop`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/) update modifier to the array:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "terms.10": { "$exists": 1 } },
    { "$pop": { "terms": 1 } },
    { "multi": true }
)
```

So the test there is for the presence of the `n-1` element in the array by index which means it must have at least that many members to match using the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator. That works opposed to [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size) which is looking for an "exact" length of the array to match.

Then the `$pop` with a positive integer in the argument removes the last entry from that array.

The alternate case would be where you just wanted to keep 10 entries in the array only regardless of length, where you could then apply the `$slice` modifier to the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) update operator:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "terms.10": { "$exists": 1 } },
    { "$push": { "terms": { "$each": [], "$slice": 10 } } },
    { "multi": true }
)
```

Where the maybe not obvious example with `$push` is when the [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier has an empty array then no changes are made (pushed) to the array, however the `$slice` is applied to restrict the overall array length. In this case, from the start of the array ( first `n` elements ) by using a positive integer. A negative comes from the "end" of the array for the "last" `n` elements.

In each case the `"multi"` modifier is used to apply the statement to all matched documents from the query condition of the update. And in both cases it's still best to just modify the documents that are a match only.

Comment: Thanks .. excellent explanation.. I have one more question can i do this while i update the array .. i mean adding the value in terms array and removing the last element if it exceeds more than 10.

Comment: @SameerSheikh For that sort of operation you should be looking at the modifiers to `$push` as mentioned. There is also `$sort` in addition to `$slice` or even `$position` whiich can help in determining which members are kept.